# For integers A>0, B>0, N>0, find integers x>0,y>0 such that N-(Ax+By) is smallest non-negative

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra

Example :

> > A=5, B=2, N=12

Then let x=2, y=1, so 12 - (5(2) + 2(1)) = 0.

Another example:

> > A=5, B=4, N=12

Here x=1, y=1 is the best possible. Note x=2, y=0 would be better except that x=0 is not allowed.

I'm looking for something fast.

**Note** it's sufficient to find the value of Ax+By. It's not necessary to give x or y explicitly.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please reword it.

Comment: See this now @bikeman868

Comment: Why 9? 5*2+4*0=10. And 5*4+4*(-2)=12.

Comment: Still doesn't make enough sense. This might help though: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c

Comment: i put constraints @Soonts

Comment: So x and y must also be positive integers?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that A+B<=N? Otherwise, there may not be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If gcd(A,B)|N, then N is your maximal value. Otherwise, it's the greatest multiple of gcd(A,B) that's smaller than N. Using 4x+2y=13 as an example, that value is gcd(4,2)*6=12 realized by 4(2)+2(2)=12 (among many solutions).

As a formula, your maximal value is Floor(N/gcd(A,B))*gcd(A,B).

**Edit:** If both x and y must be positive, this may not work. However, won't even be a solution if A+B>N. Here's an algorithm for you...

```py
from math import floor, ceil

def euclid_wallis(m, n):
    col1 = [1, 0, m]
    col2 = [0, 1, n]

    while col2[-1] != 0:
        f = -1 * (col1[-1] // col2[-1])
        col2, col1 = [x2 * f + x1 for x1, x2 in zip(col1, col2)], col2

    return col1, col2

def positive_solutions(A, B, N):
    (x, y, gcf), (cx, cy, _) = euclid_wallis(A, B)

    f = N // gcf
    while f > 0:
        fx, fy, n = f*x, f*y, f*gcf

        k_min = (-fx + 0.) / cx
        k_max = (-fy + 0.) / cy

        if cx < 0:
            k_min, k_max = k_max, k_min

        if floor(k_min) + 1 <= ceil(k_max) - 1:
            example_k = int(floor(k_min) + 1)
            return fx + cx * example_k, fy + cy * example_k, n

        if k_max <= 1:
            raise Exception('No solution - A: {}, B: {}, N: {}'.format(A, B, N))

        f -= 1

print positive_solutions(5, 4, 12) # (1, 1, 9)
print positive_solutions(2, 3, 6) # (1, 1, 5)
print positive_solutions(23, 37, 238) # (7, 2, 235)
```

Comment: what if A=5,B=3, N=12

Comment: @LalitVerma 5*3+3*(-1)=12. The original problem statement did not say that x and y had to be positive.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention but x,y should be positive integers , the above formula failed for this constraint @RaymondChen

Comment: @LalitVerma I added an algorithm in Python that accounts for that constraint, should be pretty optimal as there isn't much "force" involved.

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force `O(N^2 / A / B)` algorithm, implemented in plain Python3:

```
import math

def axby(A, B, N):
    return [A * x + B * y
            for x in range(1, 1 + math.ceil(N / A))
            for y in range(1, 1 + math.ceil(N / B))
            if (N - A * x - B * y) >= 0]

def bestAxBy(A, B, N):
    return min(axby(A, B, N), key=lambda x: N - x)
```

This matched your examples:

```
In [2]: bestAxBy(5, 2, 12)
Out[2]: 12                  # 5 * (2) + 2 * (1)

In [3]: bestAxBy(5, 4, 12)
Out[3]: 9                   # 5 * (1) + 4 * (1)
```

Comment: Once `N > LCM(A, B)`, you can stop searching because you will just be seeing the same answers over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Have no idea what algorithm that might be, but I think you need something like that (C#)

```
static class Program
{
    static int solve( int a, int b, int N )
    {
        if( a <= 0 || b <= 0 || N <= 0 )
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        if( a + b > N )
            return -1;  // Even x=1, y=1 still more then N

        int x = 1;
        int y = ( N - ( x * a ) ) / b;

        int zInitial = a * x + b * y;
        int zMax = zInitial;

        while( true )
        {
            x++;
            y = ( N - ( x * a ) ) / b;
            if( y <= 0 )
                return zMax;    // With that x, no positive y possible
            int z = a * x + b * y;
            if( z > zMax )
                zMax = z;   // Nice, found better
            if( z == zInitial )
                return zMax;    // x/y/z are periodical, returned where started, meaning no new values are expected
        }
    }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int r = solve( 5, 4, 12 );
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}", r );
    }
}
```